# MERN stack app shows a blank screen on deployment to heroku

Tags: reactjs, express, heroku, redux

I am trying for the first time ever to deploy my app to `Heroku`. I am using `create-react-app`, `redux`, with `node/express` on the backend and `Mongo DB` for the database.

When I go to my app via `heroku open`, the app is working perfectly, but when I try to view it on `incognito` mode or with any other browser, or even my phone, I am greeted with a blank screen.

Here is the link to my application: https://geekhub-kevin.herokuapp.com/

Here is the code on my `server.js`

```js
    //serve static assets if in production
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
      //set static folder
      app.use(express.static("client/build"));
      app.get("*", (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "client", "build", "index.html"));
      });
    }
```

And in my `package.json` I am using this script:

```
"heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client"
```

I apologize for not sharing more on my first draft of this post but I honestly don't know what to share to give clarity.

Comment: are you maybe adding Redux DevTools as an argument to the `compose` method? If so, your app does not work in Incognito - or any browser without the extension installed - because you can only pass functions and `compose` is trying to call `apply()` on `false`

Comment: that was it. thank you! I removed the `window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()` from the store and it worked